# Joomla JError::raiseWarning() shows twice

Tags: joomla, warnings

I'm writing a Joomla plugin that looks more or less like:

```
<?php

    // no direct access
    defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

    class plgSystemTest extends JPlugin {
        function onAfterInitialise(){
            static $showWarnings = true;

            if($somecondition && $showWarnings)
                JError::raiseWarning(100,'Some warning that shows up twice.');

            $showWarnings = false;
        }
    }

?>
```

I'm testing this plugin on Joomla 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7. While the warning does show up in each of them, it shows up twice the second time the page loads.

By the way, it's also worth noting that the `$showWarnings` flag doesn't help at all.

[image]

### Notes

- [API Documentation for JError::raiseWarning](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Error/JError.html#raiseWarning)
- [API Documentation on using messages/errors](http://docs.joomla.org/Display_error_messages_and_notices)
- [Possibly related issue](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2367310)
- [How the API is being used](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-platform/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/error/log.php)
- [Get someone to talk on IRC](http://webchat.freenode.net?channels=joomla%2Cjoomla-dev&uio=d4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @alghimo hinted, warnings are somehow stored in a session.

Unfortunately, I don't have time to waste investigating such strange issues in Joomla, so the technical details are still hazy.

The way I got it to work as I want is to not to show the message when `$_GET['layout']` is `edit`:

```
if($_REQUEST['layout'] != 'edit'){
    JError::raiseWarning(100, 'Bla bla bla.');
}
```

That said, I don't feel this is the right answer to the issue. If anyone comes up with a better idea, I'll be more than happy to switch answers accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that no other piece of code is trigerring JError::raiseWarning or the "onAfterInitialise" event?. That static var should work unless you have two different instances of the plugin.

You could try this:

```
class plgSystemTest extends JPlugin {
        function onAfterInitialise(){
            static $showWarnings;
            if ( !isset( $showWarnings ) ) {
                JError::raiseWarning(100,'Some warning that shows up twice.');
                $showWarnings = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if it still doesn't work, try this:

```
class plgSystemTest extends JPlugin {
        protected static $showWarnings;

        function onAfterInitialise(){
            if ( !isset( self::$showWarnings ) ) {
                JError::raiseWarning(100,'Some warning that shows up twice.');
                $showWarnings = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helped!

**I'm editing the answer to answer your comment**

First of all: sorry, I made a mistake on my code. In the second piece of code, you should change this:

```
$showWarnings = false
```

For this:

```
self::$showWarnings = false;
```

If it still isn't working, try this:

```
class plgSystemTest extends JPlugin {
    protected static $showWarnings = true;

    function onAfterInitialise(){
        static $call_count = null;
        if ( self::$showWarnings === true ) {
            if( !isset( $call_count ) ) {
                $call_count = 1;
            } else {
                $call_count++;
            }
            JError::raiseWarning(100,'Some warning that shows up twice. Total: ' . $call_count);
            self::$showWarnings = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: In fact, I've been using the second variant, but it didn't help at all. :(

Comment: The problem is with Joomla, I'm sure the simple switch I wrote does work as intended, but I think the call to `raiseWarning()` is somehow cached between pages.

Comment: Yes, enqueued messages are stored in session if I'm not wrong, but you should only get this message twice if you're doing some kind of redirection (for example, a "save" task usually performs a redirection). In this case, your plugin would add the message twice. But I think that a "new" task should not perform any redirections